# Uploading email archive to Google Apps email, and automatically creating contacts

Tags: google-contacts, google-apps-email, upload

I have been using Entourage, but don't have any contacts in it. Now I will upload Entourages email archive to my account on Google Apps email. I want Google Apps email to create contacts for all the email addresses in the archive.

Normally GA email automatically does that each time you reply. But since this account is completely imported it is in a virgin state.

Will GA email automatically create contacts for all the emails that have been replied to in the archive, or does it only do that for replies made on its own system from now on?
If the latter, how do I automatically batch convert all my emails into contacts with a few clicks?

Maybe I can batch select them as not spam, but this might be a risk, as there is probably some spam in the archive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GMail won't scan your uploaded sent messages to populate your address book with contacts. You have to import or create your contacts separately.

Comment: Assuming batch creating contacts from all my emails in entourage isn't possible: My only option is to filter out all emails (with names) from my archive, and then import those as contacts into gmail using one vcf file?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "filter out all emails", but there's software out there like [Entourage Address Extractor](http://www.softhing.com/eae.html) that can scan your local emails & pull out e-mail addresses from them.